# Strange chattering in derivative of InterpolatingFunction returned by NDSolve using FEM

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method, interpolation

When using the Finite Element Method of NDSolve to solve a set of ODE, the resulting `InterpolatingFunction` showcases a strange chattering in its derivatives. This behavior does not occur when using the default method or Runge-Kutta options.

Let me illustrate the issue with a very simple problem.

**DEFAULT CASE**

A reference solution can be obtained with the following code

```
w2 = 6;
m = 2;
T = 2.0;
sol = NDSolveValue[{q'[t] == ζ[t], ζ'[t] + w2*Sin[q[t]] == 0, 
                    q[0] == Pi/3., ζ[0] == 0}, {q, ζ}, {t, 0, T}]
```

Solutions are smooth. One can easily plot the time derivative of the first solution with

```
Plot[sol[[1]]'[t], {t, 0, T}]
```

**FEM CASE**

The same solutions can be obtained by using the Finite Element Method option of NDSolve:

```
solFEM = NDSolveValue[{q'[t] == ζ[t], ζ'[t] + w2*Sin[q[t]] == 0,
                       DirichletCondition[{q[t] == Pi/3., ζ[t] == 0}, t == 0]}, 
                      {q, ζ}, t ∈ Line[{{0}, {T}}], Method -> {"FiniteElement"}]
```

Of course, the solutions are also smooth in this case and the time derivative of the first solution can be plotted with

```
Plot[solFEM[[1]]'[t], {t, 0, T}]
```

We can compare both plots and see that the one coming from the Finite Element Method has some chattering to it:

[image]

This is of course just one basic example and the issue shown here tends to be more troublesome for more complicated situations.

So, why does this happen? And since I really need the FEM option for a specific scenario, how can this be avoided or treated?

**EDIT 1**

On appearance, an easy fix would have been to reduce the cell size of the FEM method. This can be achieved by setting the `"MaxCellMeasure"` size to something smaller (like 0.01 or 0.001 for example):

```
 solFEM = 
 NDSolveValue[{q'[t] == ζ[t], ζ'[t] + w2*Sin[q[t]] == 0, 
   DirichletCondition[{q[t] == Pi/3., ζ[t] == 0}, t == 0]}, 
   {q, ζ}, t ∈ Line[{{0}, {T}}], 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", "MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01}}]
```

However, this only "hides" the issue to the bare eye. One can still see the chattering effect when zooming around the minimum for example:

[image]
[image]

**Why would this matter?**

My problem with this issue has nothing to do with the curve appearance. On a practical level, if I want to determine, say, the local minimum (or maximum) near some region, then `FindMinimum` (or `FindMaximum`) will inevitably fail. I can easily find the local minimum near `t->0.5` for the "default" solution:

```
FindMinimum[sol[[1]]'[t], {t, 0.5}]
(* {-2.44949, {t -> 0.688223}} *)
```

However, this is not possible with the FEM solution because chattering obviously affects `FindMinimum`:

```
FindMinimum[solFEM[[1]]'[t], {t, 0.5}]
```

> ••• FindMinimum: The line search decreased the step size to within the tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

```
(* {-2.1981, {t -> 0.5}} *)
```

Because of chattering, this simple operation becomes impossible even when directly feeding a very close initial guess:

```
FindMinimum[solFEM[[1]]'[t], {t, 0.688223}]
```

> ••• FindMinimum: Line search unable to find a sufficient decrease in the function value with MachinePrecision digit precision.

```
(* {-2.45211, {t -> 0.69}} *)
```

This is only one example of the consequences of that chattering effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure about how to explain this behavior, but it can be circumvented by extracting the original data from the `InterpolatingFunction[…]`, calculating the derivative based on finite difference method (FDM) and recreate an `InterpolatingFunction[…]`:

```
createD = With[{values = #["ValuesOnGrid"], grid = #["Grid"] // Flatten}, 
    With[{order = Ordering@grid}, 
     ListInterpolation[
      NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[1, grid[[order]], 
       values[[order]]], {grid[[order]]}]]] &;
dq = createD@solFEM[[1]];

Plot[{sol[[1]]'[t], dq[t]} // Evaluate, {t, 0, T}, PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed}]
```

[image]

```
FindMinimum[dq[t], {t, 0.5}]
(* {-2.44878, {t -> 0.682447}} *)
```

Comment: This would have been too easy and did try that solution before. However, when you zoom-in around the minimum with `Plot[solFEM[[1]]'[t], {t, 0.6, 0.8}]`, you can easily see that the chattering is still there, only less perceptible with the bare eye...

Comment: @Meclassic I rewrite my answer, have a look :) .

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work, however I am starting to believe that the chattering does come from the interpolation performed by the FEM itself. It would be interesting to know if that behavior can be modified

Comment: @Meclassic Not that simple. Just remove the ``NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative`` in my code to rebuild a `InterpolatingFunction` for `q` using the traditional `"Hermit"` method and plot the derivative, you'll see the chattering is still there. Setting `Method->"Spline"` will remove the discontinuity, but this time the derivative is waving.